# What's the difference between Logic and SoundTrackPro?

Tags: logic-pro

I have SoundTrackPro and I'm considering of switching to Logic Pro. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Just to update this for anyone who stumbles across it in future... SoundTrack Pro has been discontinued by Apple. Logic Studio 9 is no longer available; Logic Pro is now download-only from the Mac App Store, and comes without many of the auxiliary applications that came in the "Studio" bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SoundTrack Pro is specifically targeted at creating and mixing music for video production. It has knowledge of SMTPE and other video-audio synchronization technologies and the layout is geared towards viewing video and audio simultaneously so you can score, mix and master to the visuals.

Logic Pro is targeted at just creating, mixing and mastering music. It's optimized for viewing multitrack audio, editing audio samples, working with MIDI data and other primarily audio-specific functions.

As of Logic Pro 8, SoundTrack Pro has been shipped as a sub-component of the entire Logic Studio suite of tools. So buy Logic, get SoundTrack Pro. With the release of Logic Studio 9 we're up to [SoundTrack Pro 3](http://www.apple.com/logicstudio/soundtrackpro/). So buying Logic Studio doesn't mean giving up SoundTrack Pro.